# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.area() > 0)

Tags: java, opencv

Estou tendo o seguinte erro com a biblioteca OpenCV no Java:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.area() > 0) in cv::resize, file ........\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp, line 1834

Código:

```
    Mat img = new Mat();
    // capturar primeiro frame do video 
    VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture(Options.videoAtual);
    cap.read(img);

    // passar a imagem para tons de cinza
    Mat grayImg = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, grayImg, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // aplicar filtro da media para reduzir os ruidos
    Imgproc.medianBlur(grayImg, grayImg, 7);
    Highgui.imwrite("tmp/img1.jpg", grayImg);

    // aplicar transformada circular de hough
    Mat circles = new Mat();
    Imgproc.HoughCircles(grayImg, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20, 
            180,18,minRaio,maxRaio);

    for (int x = 0; x < circles.cols(); x++) {
        double vCircle[] = circles.get(0, x);

        Point center = new Point(Math.round(vCircle[0]), Math.round(vCircle[1]));
        int radius = (int) Math.round(vCircle[2]);

        Centro = center;
        Raio = radius;

        // draw the circle outline
        Core.circle(img, center, radius, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0);
    }

    Highgui.imwrite("houghcircles.jpg", img);
```

Comment: Já descobriu qual das linhas do seu código é responsável por acionar este erro? Use o debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro indica que a imagem de origem está vazia (imagem inválida).

Tente seguir os seguintes passos:

1. Certifique-se que as bibliotecas do opencv foram devidamente linkadas;
2. Faça o teste com uma imagem carregada diretamente do disco utilizando `imread()`.
3. Se o passo 2 funcionou, adicione um `sleep()` ou um `waitkey()` após o `cap.read(img)` para aguardar uma resposta do vídeo.

Se ficou alguma dúvida, pergunte nos comentário.